# How is Passenger and ruby set up on a shared host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm trying to get Ruby on Rails apps working on a shared hosting environment running Passenger.
(Actually two, one has Ruby 2.4 and the other has Ruby 2.7.)
I cannot get either to work, as their basic Ruby version is lower than the Passenger version.
(2.4 - 2.1.6, 2.7 - 2.6.)

So far I haven't been able to get past the Gemfile loading stage.
For example, on 2.7, if I remove the ruby version I can 'bundle install'.  (uses 2.5.5) and I get

```
Could not find rake-13.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

with

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `block in materialize'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `map!'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `materialize'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/runtime.rb:101:in `block in definition_method'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler.rb:149:in `setup'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/ruby/ruby-2.7.4/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:373:in `activate_gem'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:537:in `running_bundler'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:91:in `preload_app'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:390:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

in the Backtrace.
If I put 'ruby 2.7.4' in to Gemfile I can't 'bundle install'!

So, what is happening?
How is Passenger working with the .htaccess file (or the one generated by 'Application Manager')?
How can I ensure all my gems are found by the Passenger version of bundler?  What do I need to know to get this working, basically?!!!
I've not found any documentation on to set up a shared server.  Is there any?  All I've found is standalone setups so far.
ARRRGGGHHHH!  It's been over two months!

Oh yes, here's the bare bones Gemfile generated by the Setup Ruby in cPanel.

```
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

# ruby '2.5.5'
# ruby '2.7.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'mysql2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Here is a guide I used some time ago. https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/bionic/. You need nginx (apache) with passenger, create a server block ,point passenger where the app folder is.

Comment: So, what I learned is I can change or delete the ruby version in my Gemfile - after running any processing needed  on the host (ie., via SSH, like db:migrate or asset compilation, etc.)  Then the passenger ruby will be used when running as a server.